# Website URL automatically redirects to its mobile version in Android

Tags: java, android, saxparser, xmlpullparser, rss-reader

I have been working on RSS reader project for one the job portal on the Android platform. I am using following URL

*http://rss.jobsearch.monster.com/rssquery.ashx?q=java*

This link works fine when I open from web browser but when I use same link in the code it redirects its mobile version, and application crashes with ***404- page not found*** error. Its redirects to following URL

*http://**m**.rss.jobsearch.monster.com/rssquery.ashx?q=java*

I am using following code

```
URL url = new URL(feedLink);
InputStram stream = url.openStream();
SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
SAXParser parser = factory.newSAXParser();
XMLReader reader = parser.getXMLReader();
RssHandler handler = new RssHandler();
InputSource input = new InputSource(stream);
```

What we need to do to prevent him from redirecting to its mobile version?

Comment: ithink you need this https://developer.android.com/training/app-indexing/deep-linking.html

Comment: are you showing the rss data in a list ?

Comment: You need to speak to the developer at the site. There may be a query string exception you can add to the URI to prevent the redirect. Alternatively you will need to change the User Agent to match a desktop when making the request (but to be honest, this is a bit hacky).

Answer (score 0):

You should set a specific User-Agent to prevent mobile redirection (or just prevent this rediction for your RSS feed, server-side).

Check this [Set the User-Agent Property for a SAX Parser](http://www.bytemycode.com/snippets/snippet/703/1/).